# Path in string changes when added to cell using .formula

Tags: excel

My formula is:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(lta_col_letter & 2).Formula = _
"=IFERROR(INDEX('[" & Source & "]...'!G:G,MATCH(" & versionref_col_letter & "2,'[" & Source & "]...'!B:B,0)), text(,))"
```

Source is a file path

But when run, the cell add the file name (without extension) between the sheet name (...) and the end of the reference ('!G:G).

Cannot figure it out!

Comment: I'm not sure why my variables are relevant when the issue is between the sheet name and the range where there is no variable. The formula is a standard index match looking at the source spreadsheet to return a value from G where the matched value is in B. The value being looked up is in a cell which is identified by a letter (versionref_col_letter) and the row number (2).

Answer (score 0):

Right - I've solved my issue and thought I'd share the solution I used in case others come across this.

Instead of inserting a formula into a cell I've used application.match and  Application.WorksheetFunction.Index and a for/next loop replacing dragging the formula to all rows. This means the "source" spreadsheet needs to be opened, which I was hoping to avoid, but also means I do not need to reference a full filepath to identify the source (and this is where things were going wrong when building the formula.

I've still no idea *why* it wasn't working correctly before mind!

```
Dim Found As Range, LastRow As Long
Set Found = Rows(1).Find(What:="Contact Ref.", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Columns(Found.Column + 1).EntireColumn.Insert
Cells(1, Found.Column + 1).Value = "LTA"

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Workbooks(ContactFile).Worksheets("...").Cells(i, Found.Column), Workbooks(Workbooks.Count - 1).Sheets("...").Range("E:E"), 0)) Then
    Workbooks(ContactFile).Worksheets("...").Cells(i, Found.Column + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Workbooks(Workbooks.Count - 1).Sheets("...").Range("G:G"), Application.Match(Workbooks(ContactFile).Worksheets("...").Cells(i, Found.Column), Workbooks(Workbooks.Count - 1).Sheets("...").Range("B:B"), 0))
    End If
Next i
```